# Simple Image Resize Issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to enlarge the image when user hover my images and return to its original height and width when hover out. 
I have trouble enlarge the image size to the value I wanted. It seems like image become extremely big when I hover. Not sure what I did wrong.
Thanks for the help.

```
$('#image_layout').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var $this=$(this);
            console.log($this.height());
            $(this).css("z-index", 1).animate({
                    height: "120%",
                    width: "120%"                    
                }, "fast");

            $(this).after('hfdsuhods');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).css("z-index", 0).animate({
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "100%"

                }, "fast");
        }
     }, "img");




//images are from ajax call and the sizes are varies. 
<div id='image_layout'>
    <img src='a.jpg' />
    <img src='b.jpg' />
    <img src='c.jpg' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                height: "120%",
                width: "120%"
```

That bit of code means to make the image 120% in size, which means 20% bigger than it already is. If the image is already fairly large, this makes it 20% more so. I'd change these values to something you're more comfortable with, starting with maybe 105% and going from there. It wont be an extremely large increase, but it'll at least stop it from being "extremely large" when you hover.